# Why does running Spark job fail to find classes inside uberjar on EMR while it works locally fine?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I have a Spark Job that is using some external libraries to work. When I run the job locally through the main method from IntelliJ the job runs without any issues. However, when I assembly my job into a `jarfile` (I create an UberJAR using `sbt`) and I try to run it on EMR, it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.

I have checked that the class is indeed inside the `jarfile` so it should be available for the job to run. I have also tried the `spark-submit` options `spark.driver.extraClassPath`, `spark.driver.extraLibraryPath`, `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraLibraryPath` as well as `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` and `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst`. Also, I tried doing in the code `sparkContext.addJar("/mnt/jars/myJar")`. None of them worked for me.

Also, when running on EMR I can read the log that says that the JAR was added (not sure if it is loaded on the classpath, but it should because other classes are being loaded properly):

> 15/11/02 04:10:26 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///mnt/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://172.31.42.244:44471/jars/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1446437426661

I am running out of ideas about what else to try. I have been researching and I see few tickets on the Spark JIRA board but nothing similar to my issue.

I am running on EMR release-label 4.1.0 (Spark 1.5.0), Java 7, sbt 0.13.7 and Scala 2.10.5.

Comment: What does printing out the classpath of the workers show? Can you amend the Spark app to include a dummy `map` to `println` it?

Comment: how are you submitting your job?

Comment: I am submitting my job on `EMR` using `spark-submit`. I will add the printing of the classpath on the nodes to see if I can find out what's going on.

Comment: I have added the step to print the classpath and I see the name of my class there. I am using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader`, is that the appropiate one?

Comment: Also, I just tried to do `spark-submit --master local[*]` and it didn't work either. Something wrong with `spark-submit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with `SerializationUtils` from Apache Commons Lang. There is an open issue where the class will throw a `ClassNotFoundException` even if the class is in the classpath in a multiple-classloader environment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1049

We moved away from the library and our Spark job is working fine now. The issue was not related with Spark finally.

Answer (score 0):

I think when launching your job on EMR you need to provide the s3 location for your jar dependencies [a la the manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-spark-configure.html) e.g. `-u s3://sparksupport/libs`. These jars will be added to the classpath when running spark.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using release label `emr-4.1.0` which no longer provides that option since Spark has become a native app on EMR.